# How to Convert Json to object c# To Post Data APi

Tags: c#

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 121,
        "username": "luckygirl3",
        "counter_rechecking": 0,
        "user_id": 76,
        "f_Id": "4334"
    }
}
```

How to convert it to object and post it to api. I have already know how to post but I need to post `user` object with parameters. I tried this:

```
JObject jobjects = new JObject();
JObject jobjectss = new JObject();
jobjects["user"] = jobjectss;
jobjectss["id"] = 121;
jobjectss["username"] = "luckygirlx3";
jobjectss["counter_rechecking"] = 0;
jobjectss["user_id"] = 76;
jobjectss["f_Id"] = "4334";
```

Comment: i trying to Post That Jobject to website api :v but . all Id,Username,... is inside "USER".

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to Convert Json to object c# To Post Data APi

This seems like you want to convert a JSON response to a object. If this is the case then you want to *deserialize* your JSON. You havn't posted your *Post Data* code, so I can't help much with that.

I would first map your JSON to classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("counter_rechecking")]
    public int CounterRechecking { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("f_id")]
    public string FId { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize your JSON to `RootObject` with [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

You can then access your properties like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(deserializedJson.User.Id);
Console.WriteLine(deserializedJson.User.Username);
Console.WriteLine(deserializedJson.User.CounterRechecking);
Console.WriteLine(deserializedJson.User.UserId);
Console.WriteLine(deserializedJson.User.FId);
```

I used [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) to map your attributes with `_` to nicer property members. This is optional however.

You can also use something like [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) or **Edit -> Paste Sepcial -> Paste JSON as classes** inside Visual Studio after copying your JSON to the clipboard to generate the classes for you.

Full demo at [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7JjdLA).